# Retrieving media of a model in Laravel Nova from another Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have 2 Laravel apps - One that allows users to upload images to their profile and one that is used just as an admin panel (using Nova). Both admin and user app use the same database but they are on different websites/domains. Also both apps are on the same VPS.

Is it possible to retrieve images in the UserResource in the admin app from the user app?

I've tried approach like this but no luck:

In UserResource (I'm using Ebess\AdvancedNovaMediaLibrary)

```
Images::make('Documents', 'documents')
                        ->conversionOnIndexView('thumb')
                        ->fullSize()->enableExistingMedia(),
```

In User model

```
public function registerMediaCollections() : void {
        $this->addMediaCollection('document')
            ->useDisk('media');
    }

public function documents() {
        return $this->hasMany(Media::class, 'model_id')
            ->where('collection_name', 'document');
    }
```

In filesystem config

```
'media' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => parent_public_path('img/documents'),
            'url'    => env('PARENT_APP_URL').'/img/documents',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Function parent_public_path

```
function parent_public_path($path = '')
    {
        return '/var/www/userapp.myapp.com/public_html/public'.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.ltrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) : $path);
    }
```

`PARENT_APP_URL` equals `https://userapp.myapp.com`

Comment: If they are in other app's public directory, why not just link to them directly?

Comment: @miken32 Right now they are but later they will need to be in the storage. Can you please tell me how can I link them directly so I can retrieve them in Nova as show above? I mean using the Images field

Comment: I have no idea. Sounds like a good question for the maintainer of this Ebess\AdvancedNovaMediaLibrary, unless you expect there will be enough users of that particular software to find an answer on SO.

Comment: @Paulis if the two apps are not sharing the same file system how do you expect one to find files in the other`s file system. You can save the files in a shared file system or set up a ftp connection. I would recommend using a shared file system, assuming the database is also the same, like S3.